# Android Java- array list add the same object on each iteration

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I'm facing a really strange problem. i have a 4 records stored in parse server,  i retrieve the list from parse, my code looks like that:

```
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            List<Spot> list = new ArrayList<Spot>();
            spot s;
            int index = 0;
            for (ParseObject o : objects) {
                s=jsonToSpot(o);
                list.add(s);
                Log.d("app",list.get(index).getLatLng.toString()); // return the coordinate of spot object
                index++;




            }
            Log.d("app",list.get(1).getLatLng.toString());
            Log.d("app",list.get(2).getLatLng.toString());
            Log.d("app",list.get(3).getLatLng.toString());
            Log.d("app",list.get(4).getLatLng.toString());
            getAllListener.done(list);
        }
    });


private Spot jsonToSpot(ParseObject o) {
    Log.d("app", "Model jsonToSpot");
    Spot s = new Spot(o.getDouble("latitude"), o.getDouble("longitude"));
    return s;
}
```

now the problem is that my log inside the for loop works well, which mean that it prints different Spot every iteration. but the logs that occurs after the loop, prints the same Spot, which mean that every sale in the list contain the same spot.

I cant understand what goes wrong, appreciate your help.

Comment: make spot s = new spot() inside the loop

Comment: can you post the real code? This one can't even compile

Answer (score 0):

```
spot s;
int index = 0;
for (ParseObject o : objects) {
    s=jsonToSpot(o);
    list.add(s);
    Log.d("app",list.get(index).getLatLng.toString()); // return the coordinate of spot object
    index++;
}
```

Basically what you're doing is, you're storing the reference of `s` into the last and you keep changing the value in the reference. What you should do in the loop is, create a new `Spot` in the loop each time and store that `Spot` into the list.

```
int index = 0;
for (ParseObject o : objects) {
    Spot s = jsonToSpot(o);
    list.add(s);
    Log.d("app",list.get(index).getLatLng.toString()); // return the coordinate of spot object
    index++;
}
```

The code snippet above will help you out.

Comment: i understand what your saying @kevto , but at the beginning my code was(still does not work):
 
    list.add(jsonToSpot(o));


isn't that supposed to solve the problem?

Comment: @Adamed You could do that indeed. Alternatively, you could still create a new `Spot` in the for-loop and use the content of the `jsonToSpot` method in the for-loop.

Comment: thanks for your time,i tried to use " Spot s = jsonToSpor(o)) " inside the loop,
unfortunately it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but a suggestion. You can't use 1,2,3,4 it needs to 0,1,2,3. You need to use zero offsets. The latter part of logging  could be like:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size;i++) {
    Log.d("app", "index: " + i + ", value: " + list.get(i).getLatLng.toString());
}
```

Also, might do good to check getLatLng() and see if it is returning the correct values.